# How to format a table cell into one?

Tags: formatting, adobe-indesign

So I am having an issue, (or me just being a complete Derp. I am pretty sure it's the latter) with tables and formatting.

I need to recreate a table from a Word document into my InDesign, and I basically need to make two header row into one so that two columns fit under it...

See the attached image to fully understand what I mean.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Any answers/solutions will be highly appreciated. :-)[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a practical, programming related topic. Questions on how to work with specific graphic software can be asked on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the cells to merge.
2. Invoke Menu "Table" / "Merge Cells".